# How to format a dd/mm/yyyy date in a full string date?

Tags: excel, vba

In my VBA code I receive a date from a Userform and I display it on a cell.
But, I want to have to date like that in the cell : `vendredi 1 mars 2019`  => equivalent of friday first of March of 2019 but it's in French.

But, I receive a date like that from the UserForm : `01/03/2019`

How can I format it with VBA to be in accordance of what I want ?

Comment: format the cell

Comment: No, because I insert a new row, so I want it automatically with a DateFormat something like that

Comment: So you want to convert your date into *long date* format?

Comment: I want to convert `01/03/2019` to `vendredi 1 mars 2019` with something like that I guess `NumberFormat = ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you receive the date from a textbox or something as `String` (text only), you must convert it into a real date value first. Therfore we split the string by its delimiter `/` into 3 parts (day, month, year) and use the [DateSerial function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function) to create a real date value (not a string!)

Then we write the date value into a cell and format it in the desired number format

```
[$-fr-FR]DDDD D MMMM YYYY;@
```

Which should return
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ConvertStringToDateAndFormat()
    Dim FromUserForm As String
    FromUserForm = "01/03/2019" 'assuming you get a string from a textbox or something

    'split date into 3 parts 
    Dim SplitDate As Variant
    SplitDate = Split(FromUserForm, "/")

    'check if we got 3 parts
    If UBound(SplitDate) <> 2 Then
        MsgBox "invalid date"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'write into cell and format cell
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A1").Value = DateSerial(SplitDate(2), SplitDate(1), SplitDate(0))
        .Range("A1").NumberFormat = "[$-fr-FR]DDDD D MMMM YYYY;@"
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that this will format the date French even if used on an English Excel. If you want to format it in the language the usere is actually using in his Excel/Windows then use `.NumberFormat = "DDDD D MMMM YYYY;@"` which will be French in a French Windows and German in a German Windows.

Comment: Why It's note `"vendredi 10 décembre 1940"` when I use this format ? But if I click on the cell I see `"01/03/2019"`

Comment: It's working perfectly without the `[$-fr-FR]` !! Thanks a lot