# Common Date formatting formula for English and German

Tags: excel, date, format

I have a formula in Excel to format date in specified format (`=text(date,"dd-mm-yyyy")`, the file is also used in swiss and their system date setting in german(swiss). So its not showing it correctly. How to do that in Formula ?

I dont want to Format the cell. I need it in formula.

```
=text(date,"dd-mm-yyyy")
```

The file will be used by both the users (english and german). need a comon formula for that. and also how to do the same in vba. i used

```
format$(date,"dd-mm-yyyy")
```

for english.

Comment: [Check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58059060/11936678) which might have some usable answers for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Code adapted from http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?33984-How-to-GET-the-system-date-format-from-regional-settings

Option Explicit

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetLocaleInfoA" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) As Long
Private Const LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT = &H400
Private Const LOCALE_SSHORTDATE = &H1F ' short date format string
Private Const LOCALE_SLONGDATE = &H20 ' long date format string

Function LocaleString()
    Dim strLocale As String
    Dim lngRet As Long
    Dim strMsg As String

    'Get short date format
    strLocale = Space(255)
    lngRet = GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SSHORTDATE, strLocale, Len(strLocale))
    strLocale = Left(strLocale, lngRet - 1)
    LocaleString = strLocale
End Function

Function CDateLocale(d As Date) As String
  CDateLocale = Format(d, LocaleString())

End Function
```

With this in a module, you can use =CDateLocale(A1) to convert the date in A1 into the local shortdate format but as text rather than a date.